EF Core - Custom property in query
I have an entity represeting exercise training set:
public partial class TrainingSetEntity
{
    public int? RepCount { get; set; }
    public double? WeightLiftedKilograms { get; set; }
}

and I want to add custom property that doesn't represent column from the table but is calculated based on RepCount and WeightLiftedKilograms. And I want to use this property directly in LINQ queries.
This old blog was describing a way how to achieve this, but when I tried that, EF wasn't able to translate the query.
I have tried:
public partial class TrainingSetEntity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public double EstimatedOneRepMaxBrzycki => EstimatedOneRepMaxFunc(this);

    private static Expression<Func<TrainingSetEntity, double>> EstimatedOneRepMaxExpression = tSet =>
        tSet.WeightLiftedKilograms == null || tSet.RepCount == null
            ? 0D
            : tSet.WeightLiftedKilograms.Value * (36D / (37D - (tSet.RepCount.Value > 10 ? 10 : tSet.RepCount.Value)));

    private static Func<TrainingSetEntity, double> EstimatedOneRepMaxFunc = EstimatedOneRepMaxExpression.Compile();
}

Does is still work in new EF Core (we use EF Core 8) ? Or are there any alternatives to do use custom property in query like:
await Context.Set<TrainingSetEntity>()
    .OrderByDescending(tSet => tSet.EstimatedOneRepMaxBrzycki)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);


It is possible with third party extansions, like LINQKit, ExpressionDecompiler, NeninLinq. If you are ready to use them i'll post links to SO answers.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv why 3rd party extensions are needed for this ? Couldnt this be simply achieved with vanilla C# like in the blogpost ?

What happens if you use it? You don't show code actually using the expression.

Yes, if you know how to intercept EF Core's QueryExpression and do the same thing what these libraries do. Without transforming Expression Tree it is not possible.

So if I understand this correctly. In old EF (before core) this was possible to do also without these libs but current EF Core makes this more complicated to do manually and thus it is better to use those 3rd party libs ? If yes can you please create an answer using one of them ?

This old post is doing simpe thing - generate Where predicate, which is stightforwasrd. It is not your case, you need other approach, EstimatedOneRepMaxBrzycki should be converible to SQL, but is not.
